# What are the directories containing `/etc/data/security/limits.d` and `/etc/udev/rules.d/` in Linux mint?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

In Ubuntu there exist the directories containing `/etc/data/security/limits.d` and `/etc/udev/rules.d/`. Where can I get the same information these directories provide in Linux Mint (specifically Mint 20.1)? I want to give privileges to groups. by adding a `.conf` and `.rules` files respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Mint the directory is `/etc/security/limits.d`.

If the `/etc/udev/rules.d/` doesn't exist, create it.

the manpage explain how `udev` read rules:

```
The udev rules are read from the files located in the system rules
directories /lib/udev/rules.d and /usr/local/lib/udev/rules.d, the
volatile runtime directory /run/udev/rules.d and the local
administration directory /etc/udev/rules.d.
```